# Self signed certificate jQuery AJAX in Mosync

Tags: jquery, https, self-signed, mosync

**Background:**
I've seen a few questions like this one, but none that actually answer this.

I am attempting to use a self signed certificate on a webservice to prove SLL encryption when I communicate to the server.  The server is pretty old and established and in this context a self signed certificate is acceptable/required (I know it's a bad practice in general, but it's happening here and that's not the point of this question).

We're developing a mobile application using Mosync to package an HTML5/jQuery app as a new client to the server.  When we don't use https/SSL (in our development environments) we are able to make all our AJAX calls successfully.  As soon as we introduce https/SLL our calls stop even being made.  From previous searching I think this is because of the self signed cert.

**Main Question:**
Is there any way to force jQuery to continue despite the cert being self signed?  Would we be able to accomplish this by installing the cert on the device (primarily targeting Android for now)?  Is there a Mosync option to work around this?
Or, is there absolutely no way around this and we have to either use http or a CA signed cert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in MoSync's runtime libraries which currently doesn't handle SSL errors from the WebView.

MoSync is aware of the [issue](http://jira.mosync.com/browse/MOSYNC-2924) and we're working on a solution that will be made available soon. Please keep a watch on the issue to know when a build of MoSync incorporating the fix will be available.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.  We'll keep an eye on that and make sure to update.